# How to read text file form particular directory in ios app?

Tags: swift

I want to read text file in my ios app. **test1** folder contains **one.txt** file. When I remove this "**inDirectory:"test1"**"  my code works correctly. But I want to mention the folder name. How to do that ?

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "one", ofType: "txt" , 

 inDirectory:"test1" )

    {
        text2 = try! String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8)
    }
    else
    {
        print("file not found")
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add files and folders with settings: `Create group`
[image]

Then you shouldn't setup folder in this case (system create `ipa` file and put all file together in one place).
When you add files with `references` it create folder inside `ipa`. Don't forget to check this files in the target list.

Answer (score -1):

In *macOS*, create a folder name it *test1*, put the `txt` file inside it and drag it into Xcode. Make sure *Create folder references* is selected:

[image]

...then your code should work.

[image: look to console output of txt file in run]

Comment: I tried it and it worked with me successfully why the down voting ???????

Comment: Probably for your terrible, **terrible** formatting.

Comment: Oh , I thought the answer was wrong , thnks  now up vote plz

Comment: You should not ask for upvotes. Improve your answer so that it actually helps OP understand and solve their issue. Then you'll be rewarded.

Comment: number of reputations prevents me from a lot of things needs 50 at least

Comment: You can always come up with good content and edit your own answer.